# how can I fetch content in tinymce from jsp to servlet which in turn redirected to another page?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jsp, servlets

The contents from the tinymce editor is to be stored and is to be post with new page creation. How should I proceed?

[image]

Comment: Capture the content of the `tinymce` editor then, add it to an element in the new page... Now how are you opening the new page (just new window, call to a document on a server?), share some of your code to understand what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a form around the textarea which will be initialized with tinymce like the following

```
<form name="submitForm" method="post" action="saveAction">
    <textarea id="mytextarea" name="content">Rich html text here</textarea>
</form>
```

Second, Create a server side saveAction (servlet) to accept the form request and save the content to the database.  The content will be in html format.

Finally, Create a new server side servlet to load the content from the database and pass it to the client for display

Comment: It depends on what your architecture design is.  If you go with relational DB, you can use Hibernate or similar.  If you decided to store as flat file somewhere, then you can use [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html).  Like the FileUtils.writeStringToFile(...).  You have to narrow down your question on what you have in mind on the design.